# How to create ICMP Code-3 error

Tags: icmp

I made lots of search but couldn't find useful info about how create ICMP Code-3 (dest. unreachable) error and capture it with Wireshark. I tried to ping a closed port in Linux machine and also used host command but nothing. Could anyone help me about this please? I need to analyze the datagram.
Thank you.

Comment: What kind of "code 3" do you want? There are a lot of sub errors! [See link](http://www.nthelp.com/icmp.html)

Comment: Oh sorry, the sub-code would be Code-3 Port Unreachable. Thanks for the notification.

Answer (score 0):

I´ve seen these error if I want to ping a computer from one subnet into another subnet connected over a vpn connection if the vpn connection isn´t available. But I think it will not be the same sub error that you´re looking for. But maybe it will poke you in the right direction.